# In MEAN Im not able to diplay list from database mongodb into angularjs

Tags: express

smart guys plz help me...im not able to display list of data from my database into a page i must be super-duper wrong somewhere correct me please...

firstly in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "IdeationApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.10.2",
    "express": "^4.11.1",
    "mongojs": "^0.18.1"
  }
```

trying to get data in list.html:

```html
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Number</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in y ">
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.email}}</td>
      <td>{{x.number}}</td>
      <tr>
  </table>
  <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

in my controller.js:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        console.log("Hello World from controller");

        var getdata = function() {
          $http.get('/listentery').success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data I requested..................");
            //console.log(response);
            $scope.dataa = response;
            $scope.contact = "";
            //console.log($scope.dataa);
            //console.log($scope.contact);
          });
        };

        $scope.list = function() {
          console.log('calling list');
          getdata();
          $http.get('/list').success(function(response) {
            console.log($scope.dataa);

          });
        };
```

finally in my server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('idealist', ['idealist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path= require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/listentery', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I received a GET request');
  db.idealist.find(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.get('/list', function(req, res) {
  console.log('I received a GET request');
  res.sendFile((path.join(__dirname + '/public/list.html')));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your angular scope variable "y" is not defined, you should update your angular code like below:

```
       $scope.getData = function() {
          $http.get('/listentery')
          .success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data I requested..................");
            $scope.data = response;
            $scope.contact = "";
          });
       };

       $scope.getData();
```

And you should update your html codes like below

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Number</th>

    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>{{x.name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.email}}</td>
      <td>{{x.number}}</td>
      <tr>
  </table>
  <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

I hope this will be help you.

**UPDATED:** I make some changes in angular code.

Comment: silly me i for got to edit while raising this question ... im sry its "dataa" bt sill its not getting that data... thats the problem

Comment: you should handle err object in query on server-side, it's throw err object, console.log(err.message) will be help you whats going wrong.

Comment: moreover in **$scope.list** its not able to define _$scope.dataa _.... plz plz help mee...